# How can I use the shadow catcher on an object and sill get its shadow and ambient occlusion?

Tags: shadowcatcher, ambient-occlusion

Im making a house on the side of a real and bigger house, so I modeled the real house to get its shadows and ambient occlusion, but when I activate the shadow catcher, they dissapear. ¿Is there a way to get them back?

Comment: When I test it with a fresh scene I can't reproduce the issue. A red plane used as shadow catcher still reflects red onto a cube standing on it.

It should actually be turned on by default but make sure that all day visibilities on the shadow catcher are enabled.

If it still doesn't work please try again with a simple setup in a new scene to see if you can reproduce the problem. Also let us know the blender version you're using please.

Comment: I moved everything to a new scene and it seems to be working now, thank you for the quick response. I was using 2.83